# Adding products to Google Base/Content in Magento?

Tags: magento, google-base

I've been trying to add the products in my Magento store to Google's product search for the last day. I was using the built-in Google base, then found that that 'API' was retired a month or two ago and that the Magento Connect 'Google Content' plugin is what I should be using.

Having installed that, when I then try and add products to Google Content all I ever get is:

"Captcha confirmation error." (I'm typing the captcha correctly).

I've mapped all the required attributes accordingly and all my Google merchant account settings as they should be in Magento's configuration.

Couldn't find anyone with the same issue via Google or Stackexchange, but hopefully someone will have an idea for as to where to start troubleshooting! I've tried adding individual products, not just the whole lot...

Ideas?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? We're having the same issue at the moment

Comment: No, not yet unfortunately. :(

Comment: How frustrating, we're getting exactly the same result as you, we can't be the only two people with this problem can we!?

Answer (score 1):

Install this extension :

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Magento+Core/extension/6887/mage_googleshopping
```

From Mage Core team

Comment: That's the extension I have installed, that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: did you manage to run all the install scripts and upgrades properly?

Comment: Yep, all up to date (latest stable release), no other extensions installed (no conflictions), no problems until now...

Answer (score 1):

I've just managed to solve our problem, in the settings for Google API there is an 'Account Type' dropdown, I've set this to google and now the CAPTCHA problem isn't tripping things up and it's submitting product to our merchant account.

Comment: Mine has been set to 'Google' all along, still getting the same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

log into your google account then put this in the address bar:

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: Do NOT put advertisements in your posts. They belong in the "About Me" section of your profile.